# How to run Start-Job to bring up vagrant VM's separately

Tags: powershell, vagrant

I am very new to Powershell, but through looking at several other related questions I've put together the below block of code:

```
Get-Content .\test-vagrant-box-list.txt | %{
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { param($boxName) vagrant up $boxName } -Argument $_
}
```

My goal is to start four vagrant VM's in parallel through powershell. I run this script and it executes and starts each job, however it gives me the below error when I run "Receive-Job ":

```
The machine with the name 'worker1' was not found configured for
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The machine wit... configured for:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

this Vagrant environment.
NotSpecified: (:) [], RemoteException
```

These VM names are definitely defined and match up to what I have in my Vagrantfile. I made sure if i run the command "vagrant up " that they begin to build. Only through this powershell script it seems it can't find the VM's defined with that name though.

** I have looked at the -parallel flag for vagrant but in my case it doesn't seem to actually work. This was my solution instead.

Comment: When you use Start-Job you have to provide EVERY argument, function, module and variable for the job. Nothing from your current session is available to the job unless you provide it in your command.

Comment: @Scepticalist This seems pretty straight forward. Clearly the "vagrant" executable is available in the job's runspace; it just doesn't understand the argument 'worker1'.  OP should try `Invoke-Command -AsJob` instead of `Start-Job`, and pass the arguments as an array like so, `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Block -ArgumentList @(,$_) -AsJob`.